# Authorize.net DPM, How To?

Tags: php, phpunit, authorize.net

I found the DPM PHP SDK on authorize.net at http://developer.authorize.net/api/dpm/, and tried to test but it's not working, the page displays the error: Warning: require_once(PHPUnit/Framework.php).
Does someone know how to resolve this, or can provide me with step by step tutorial?

Comment: was the link to the short tutorial helpful for you ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems a requirement of the following statement has been forgotten

The PHP SDK contains a helper function that implements a demonstration of the Direct Post Method in one line of code. Copy and paste the code below into a new file named "direct_post.php" and **fill in any incomplete variables**. Make sure your **server is publicly accessible** and that the **$url variable points to this new file**.

*look at a short tutorial*

[Tutorial "15 Minutes or less"](https://developer.authorize.net/integration/fifteenminutes/#directpost)

Comment: I didn't understand what you meant at the begining, but when I found the solution, now I undesrtand. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I just had to create a php file and put this code:

```
require_once 'anet_php_sdk/AuthorizeNet.php'; // The SDK
$url = "http://YOUR_DOMAIN.com/file_I_created.php";
$api_login_id = 'YOUR_API_LOGIN_ID';
$transaction_key = 'YOUR_TRANSACTION_KEY';
$md5_setting = 'YOUR_API_LOGIN_ID'; // Your MD5 Setting
$amount = "5.99";
AuthorizeNetDPM::directPostDemo($url, $api_login_id, $transaction_key, $amount, $md5_setting);
```